# Add space *after* paragraph?

Tags: formatting, parskip

I have a document and I am happy with the spacing everywhere except where there are two sequential paragraphs. In this case I would like a line between them, but I do not know how to make this happen other than manually placing line breaks (`\\`).

I am aware of `\parskip`, but this adds space before the paragraph, not after it, which affects the entire document (e.g. space is added between paragraphs and headings, between single lines of text, between list items, etc etc)

**How can I specify a line should be added between two successive paragraphs, and only between two successive paragraphs?**

Comment: Paragraphs are everywhere in LaTeX. Every list is a paragraph, every float is a separate paragraphs with slightly different spacing. Normally, package  `parskip` is used for what you want.

Comment: `\\ ` outside of tabular material is almost always wrong.

Comment: `\parskip` is added exactly where you say you want space added, between paragraphs, document classes that set this non zero (or the `parskip` package to alter standard classes) adjust space around headings and lists etc to take account of the parskip space that will also be added. (`\\ ` at the end of a paragraph does not add vertical space, just force a spurious extra line of the paragraph, so that isn't ever a good markup)

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @ebo Thanks!
(at) David I saw Andres question before but now I re-read it with Johannes comments in mind, it does seem to answer the question, so I have accepted that it as duplicate (not sure if I should delete this or if the system will?)